# Ubuntu 22.10 HDMI port not working Intel graphics. Xrandr doesn't detect hdmi, only display ports

Tags: xrandr, intel-graphics

I am new to the linux OS and when I installed kubuntu my hdmi port doesn't seem to be working

I'm on a 12th gen intel with up to date graphic drivers

```
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1235U
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version (2:2.99.917+git20210115-1). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ xrandr --verbose
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x48) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
        Identifier: 0x42
        Timestamp:  3825649
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
        Brightness: 1.0
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        EDID: 
                00ffffffffffff000dae6f1700000000
                111e0104a52615780305c5975b538f27
                20505400000001010101010101010101
                010101010101363680a0703820403020
                a5007dd61000001a242480a070382040
                3020a5007dd61000001a000000000000
                00000000000000000000000000000002
                000c3dff0d3c7d1210237d00000000e3
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        scaling mode: Full aspect 
                supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        panel orientation: Normal 
                supported: Normal, Upside Down, Left Side Up, Right Side Up
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CONNECTOR_ID: 236 
                supported: 236
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x48) 138.780MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1095 total 1112           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x49) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1960 total 2000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4b) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4c) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4d) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1400x1050 (0x4e) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1600x900 (0x4f) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
  1600x900 (0x50) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x900 (0x51) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x52) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
  1280x1024 (0x53) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1400x900 (0x54) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
  1400x900 (0x55) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x960 (0x56) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x57) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x58) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
  1368x768 (0x59) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1368x768 (0x5a) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
  1280x800 (0x5b) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x800 (0x5c) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
  1280x800 (0x5d) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x800 (0x5e) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1280x720 (0x5f) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x60) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x61) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x62) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x63) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x64) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x65) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x66) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x67) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x68) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x69) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x6a) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x6b) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x6c) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x6d) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x6e) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
  960x540 (0x6f) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  960x540 (0x70) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
  960x540 (0x71) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
  800x600 (0x72) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x73) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x74) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x75) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x76) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  864x486 (0x77) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  864x486 (0x78) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
  700x525 (0x79) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  800x450 (0x7a) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
  800x450 (0x7b) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
  640x512 (0x7c) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  700x450 (0x7d) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
  700x450 (0x7e) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
  640x480 (0x7f) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x80) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x405 (0x81) 22.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  422           clock  59.51Hz
  720x405 (0x82) 21.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  58.99Hz
  684x384 (0x83) 42.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  720 end  788 total  892 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.88Hz
  684x384 (0x84) 36.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.85Hz
  640x400 (0x85) 41.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  676 end  740 total  840 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  415           clock  59.88Hz
  640x400 (0x86) 35.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  411           clock  59.98Hz
  640x360 (0x87) 37.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  374           clock  59.86Hz
  640x360 (0x88) 31.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  370           clock  59.83Hz
  640x360 (0x89) 18.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  376           clock  59.84Hz
  640x360 (0x8a) 17.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.32Hz
  512x384 (0x8b) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x8c) 23.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  532 end  580 total  648 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  299           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x8d) 21.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.92Hz
  480x270 (0x8e) 20.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  496 end  544 total  608 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  281           clock  59.63Hz
  480x270 (0x8f) 18.625MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.82Hz
  400x300 (0x90) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x91) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  432x243 (0x92) 16.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  444 end  484 total  536 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  253           clock  59.92Hz
  432x243 (0x93) 15.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.57Hz
  320x240 (0x94) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
  360x202 (0x95) 11.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  372 end  404 total  448 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  211           clock  59.51Hz
  360x202 (0x96) 10.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.13Hz
  320x180 (0x97)  9.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  332 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  188           clock  59.84Hz
  320x180 (0x98)  8.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.32Hz
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x43
        Timestamp:  3825649
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        subconnector: Unknown 
                supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CONNECTOR_ID: 245 
                supported: 245
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x48) 138.780MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1095 total 1112           clock  60.00Hz
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x44
        Timestamp:  3825649
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        subconnector: Unknown 
                supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CONNECTOR_ID: 258 
                supported: 258
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x48) 138.780MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1095 total 1112           clock  60.00Hz
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x45
        Timestamp:  3825649
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        subconnector: Unknown 
                supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CONNECTOR_ID: 267 
                supported: 267
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x48) 138.780MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1095 total 1112           clock  60.00Hz
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        Identifier: 0x46
        Timestamp:  3825649
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
                supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
        Content Protection: Undesired 
                supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
        vrr_capable: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
        Colorspace: Default 
                supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
        max bpc: 12 
                range: (6, 12)
        Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
                supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
        audio: auto 
                supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
        subconnector: Unknown 
                supported: Unknown, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI, DP, Wireless, Native
        link-status: Good 
                supported: Good, Bad
        CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
                0 1 
        CONNECTOR_ID: 276 
                supported: 276
        non-desktop: 0 
                range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x48) 138.780MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.72KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1090 end 1095 total 1112           clock  60.00Hz
```

The xrandr displays all my outputs as DP which I'm guessing involves some virtualization

I tried outputting to all crtcs (0-3) on all display ports but they all failed to configure.

```
$ xrandr --verbose --output DP-1 --crtc 0 --mode 1920x1080
crtc 0:    1920x1080  60.00 +0+0 "DP-1"
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
crtc 0: disable
crtc 1: disable
crtc 2: disable
crtc 3: disable
screen 0: revert
crtc 0: revert
crtc 1: revert
crtc 2: revert
crtc 3: revert
```